# Phoenix/Ecto - query for match in array of objects

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

(Ecto.Query.CompileError) `any(l.signers)` is not a valid query expression.

```
(from l in Listing, where: "xxxxxx@gmail.com" == any(l.signers))
    |> Repo.all()
```

Comment: What is your question, btw?

Answer (score 3):

[`Ecto.Query.API.in/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#in/2) is supposed to be used to cover [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) `ANY` selector.

```elixir
where: ^mail_addr in l.signers
```

It is assumed that `l.signers` is an enumerable.

Comment: I am getting this error 

value `"xxxxxx@gmail.com"` in `where` cannot be cast to type {:array, :string} in query:

Answer (score -4):

select id,address,owners from listings where 'xxxxxx@gmail.com' = ANY(signers);

This query is working in PostgreSQL.